# Visual Studio Code terminal messy after update

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code just updated. This update destroyed the entire looks of the integrated terminal. Spacing between letters seems to be set to some absurd high number.

Does anyone know how I can fix this so the terminal will look as it did before the update?

This is what it currently looks like.
[image]

Comment: A similar thing happened to me a few days ago. Have you been able to get this issue resolved yet? Looking for answers.

Comment: @ShawnSpencer if I remember corretly it was due to me opening a project from the wrong folder. No clue how that effected it but I could not open the project one folder above the package.json.